# Getting exception while deploying adf application in Apache tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, oracle-adf

I have developed an Oracle ADF application and configured the Data source name and made changes as mentioned [here](https://technology.amis.nl/2014/01/03/deploy-oracle-adf-essentials-web-application-on-tomcat/) .After deploying the ADF war file  in webapps folder I clicked on start command from tomcat web application manager console at `localhost:8080/manager/html/start` then i am getting

**below message**

> FAIL - Application at context path [/HrEntry_ViewController1_webapp]
>   could not be started FAIL - Encountered exception
>   [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/HrEntry_ViewController1_webapp]]]

**Below is the catalina log**

> 04-Apr-2018 02:07:38.227 INFO [localhost-startStop-2]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web
>   application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\sample.war]
>       04-Apr-2018 02:07:44.133 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was
>   scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this
>   logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were
>   found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve
>   startup time and JSP compilation time.
>       04-Apr-2018 02:07:44.164 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web
>   application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\sample.war] has finished in [5,953] ms
>       04-Apr-2018 02:07:54.180 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context
>   [/sample]
>       04-Apr-2018 02:07:54.258 INFO [localhost-startStop-3] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web
>   application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\sample.war]
>       04-Apr-2018 02:07:58.242 INFO [localhost-startStop-3] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was
>   scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this
>   logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were
>   found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve
>   startup time and JSP compilation time.
>       04-Apr-2018 02:07:58.242 INFO [localhost-startStop-3] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web
>   application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\sample.war] has finished in [3,984] ms
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:21.007 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-nio-8080"]
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:21.117 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-nio-8009"]
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:21.195 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service
>   [Catalina]
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:21.241 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-nio-8080"]
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:21.241 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-nio-8009"]
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version: 
>   Apache Tomcat/8.5.29
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:
>   Mar 5 2018 13:11:12 UTC
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:
>   8.5.29.0
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:
>   Windows Server 2012 R2
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:
>   6.3
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:
>   amd64
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:
>   1.8.0_161-b12
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:
>   Oracle Corporation
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:
>   C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:
>   C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\temp
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache
>   Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\conf\logging.properties
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: exit
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: abort
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Xms128m
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Xmx256m
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR
>   based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in
>   production environments was not found on the java.library.path:
>   [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat
>   8.5\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap\;;.]
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.616 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-nio-8080"]
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.882 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a
>   shared selector for servlet write/read
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.897 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-nio-8009"]
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.897 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a
>   shared selector for servlet write/read
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:34.897 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in
>   2004 ms
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:35.147 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting
>   service [Catalina]
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:35.147 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet
>   Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.29
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:35.194 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web
>   application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\ADFTomcatDemo_ViewController_webapp.war]
>       04-Apr-2018 02:08:35.819 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs Failed to
>   scan
>   [file:/C:/Program%20Files/oracle_common/modules/oracle.osdt/osdt_cert.jar]
>   from classloader hierarchy
>        java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\oracle_common\modules\oracle.osdt\osdt_cert.jar (The system
>   cannot find the path specified)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.jar.JarFile.(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.jar.JarFile.(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:188)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.(JarFileUrlJar.java:65)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:49)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:374)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:309)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:266)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:229)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1888)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1116)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:765)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5113)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
>         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: From your log file: Failed to scan [file:/C:/Program%20Files/oracle_common/modules/oracle.osdt/osdt_cert.jar] from classloader hierarchy java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\oracle_common\modules\oracle.osdt\osdt_cert.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)